# Bootstrap 3.3.7 Carousel анимация элементовах

Tags: bootstrap, анимация, carousel

Здравствуйте уважаемые девелоперы. есть скрипт который анимирует элементы в каруселе, но проблема в том что он анимацию делает только in или out, а нужно и при появлении слайда так и когда он уходит. также задержка, скорость. Если считаете что я наглею, тогда помоги добавить анимацию к картинке и надписям при исчезновении слайда. при появлении как я уже писал анимация есть.

```
  <!-- START SLİDER -->
  <div class="carousel-wrap">
    <div class="container">
      <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide carousel-fade">

        <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
        <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
          <div class="item active">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-xs-8">
                <img src="images/slide2.jpg" alt="Slide 2" class="imageUp">
              </div>
              <div class="col-xs-4">
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                  <h1>Welcome to Crisp.</h1>
                  <p>I am a mighty - awesome designer portfolio.</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-xs-8">
                <img src="images/slide2.jpg" alt="Slide 2" class="">
              </div>
              <div class="col-xs-4">
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                  slideer 2
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="control-wrap">
          <!-- Controls -->
          <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
          </a>
          <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

```
    (function( $ ) {

    //Function to animate slider captions 
    function doAnimations( elems ) {
        //Cache the animationend event in a variable
        var animEndEv = 'webkitAnimationEnd animationend';

        elems.each(function () {
            var $this = $(this),
                $animationType = $this.data('animation');
        // requires you add [data-delay] & [data-dur] in markup. values are in ms
        $animDur = parseInt($this.data('dur'));
        $animDelay = parseInt($this.data('delay'));

            $this.css({"animation-duration": $animDur + "ms", "animation-delay": $animDelay + "ms", "animation-fill-mode": "both"}).addClass($animationType).one(animEndEv, function () {
                $this.removeClass($animationType);
            });
        });
    }

    //Variables on page load 
    var $myCarousel = $('#carousel-example-generic'),
        $firstAnimatingElems = $myCarousel.find('.item:first').find("[data-animation ^= 'animated']");

    //Initialize carousel 
    $myCarousel.carousel();

    //Animate captions in first slide on page load 
    doAnimations($firstAnimatingElems);

    //Pause carousel  
    $myCarousel.carousel('pause');


    //Other slides to be animated on carousel slide event 
    $myCarousel.on('slide.bs.carousel', function (e) {
        var $animatingElems = $(e.relatedTarget).find("[data-animation ^= 'animated']");
        doAnimations($animatingElems);
    });  

})(jQuery);

var carouselContainer = $('.carousel');
var slideInterval = 5000;

    function toggleH(){
        $('.imageUp').hide()
        var caption = carouselContainer.find('.active').find('.imageUp').addClass('animated fadeInUpBig').one('webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend',
            function (){
            $(this).removeClass('animated fadeInUpBig')});
    caption.slideToggle();
    }

    function toggleC(){
        $('.toggleCaption').hide()
        var caption = carouselContainer.find('.active').find('.toggleCaption').addClass('animated fadeInUp').one('webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend',
            function (){
            $(this).removeClass('animated fadeInUp')
    });
    caption.slideToggle();
    }
carouselContainer.carousel({
interval: slideInterval, cycle: true, pause: "hover"})
.on('slide.bs.carousel slid.bs.carousel', toggleH).trigger('slide.bs.carousel')
.on('slide.bs.carousel slid.bs.carousel', toggleC).trigger('slide.bs.carousel');
```